# How to deploy maven project on aws with Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: maven, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a java maven project on aws with Gitlab CI/CD.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - test
    - build
    - deploy

maven-test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Test stage"
        - mvn clean validate compile test -B


maven-build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Build stage"
        - mvn install -B -DskipTests
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - ./target/*.jar

maven-deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploy stage"
        - scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -I "mykey.pem" ./target/*.jar ubuntu@xxxxxxx.com:*.jar
    when: manual
```

If I execute the scp command on a terminal in my pc then the jar is uploaded in aws ec2 instance while in gitlab I have errors and the jar is not uploaded.

This is my first approach with Gitlab CI and aws, so can someone explain step by step what I need to do to deploy the project in aws ec2 instance with Gitlab CI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted much about your problem nor did you post the error I will just suggest a few things to look at:

**From a GitLab perspective:**

1. Are you sure that the "mykey.pem" is available within the repository when running that command(`maven-deploy`) on the the gitlab-runner.?
2. Also are you sure that you are using a **[docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)**, if you are not then you can't use the `image:` directive and therefore it  might not not have mvn/scp locally.
3. You might want to look into the [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) directive and ensure you make that artifact available in next task. This should be done by default!

**From an AWS perspective:**

1. Make sure that the ubuntu target machine/server has port 22 exposed to the EC2 machine running the gitlab-runner.

**Edit:**

If the error you are receiving is with the pem files permissions then take a look at this resolution for [AWS EC2 pem file issue](https://99robots.com/how-to-fix-permission-error-ssh-amazon-ec2-instance/). Another similar resolution is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open).

**Seems like if you put chmod 400 mykey.pem before the scp it might fix your problem.**

Comment: The error that I have is permissions 0666 for ‘mykey.pem, are too open

Comment: If that is your error then please take a look at this [link](https://99robots.com/how-to-fix-permission-error-ssh-amazon-ec2-instance/). It talks about how to avoid this error on a AWS EC2. Seems like if you put `chmod 400 mykey.pem` before the scp it might fix it.