# How to deploy maven project in aws ec2 instance without pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612422/how-to-deploy-maven-project-on-aws-with-gitlab-ci-cd) I solved a problem of deployin a Maven project on AWS EC2 instance with Gitlab CI/CD by using SSH with PEM file, but I have read on Internet that it is not a best practice to commit the .pem file in a Git repository. So how do I have to change to deploy my application on aws without using pem file.

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@adhasmana/how-to-deploy-node-js-app-on-aws-with-gitlab-24fabde1088d) but here the application is written with node.js while my app is built with maven so what do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter what language is used to write an application. The tutorial is correct: you should use [GitLab CI/CD environment variables](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#variables) to store secrets such as keys.

[image]

Variables are exposed as environment variables at the build time. You can use them like:

```
production:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine/latest
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  script:
    - ./deploy # This script uses SSH to deploy things
    - ssh-agent -k
```

Comment: In the tutorial the repo is cloned in the AWS instance. After my build stage I only want to deploy the artifact in my AWS instance. So I edit the updateAndRestart.sh file. I delete the all things and I put an scp command in this way: `scp ./target/*.jar ubuntu@$DEPLOY_SERVERS:*.jar` but this give me error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not know`

Comment: Have you created `DEPLOY_SERVERS` variable with your target host? Did you put instance's **public** host / IP in that variable?

Comment: Yes. I l’ve also tried to write directly the public DNS name but I’ve the error: `Host key verification failed`